# Фильтрация дискретного сигнала

Tags: c++, qt, фильтры, фильтрация, цос

На фото есть кривая, которая в общем случае через каждые Δx состоит из двух точек (в реальности это координаты двух рядом проложенных проводов).

Необходимо убрать лишний шум и оставить лишь координаты, относящиеся непосредственно к этим кривым.

Каким образом лучше фильтровать данный сигнал?

Задачу осложняет то, что есть участки, где координаты одного из проводов не были записаны, поэтому самый простой вариант - оставить лишь по две точки в некотором диапазоне координат, не работает.

Моя идея - каким-то образом определить провод, зная что его координаты плавно изменяются на всем промежутке (исключить резкие скачки). Но каким образом можно математически описать эту "плавность"?

Задачу решаю на С++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно вам нужно *среднее квадратическое*. http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5 оно лучше сглаживает сигнал чем *среднее арифметическое*

Comment: В данном случае, выбор инструмента не принципиален, даже наоборот - я бы погонял данные в матлабе / сайлабе / R, а потом перенес бы алгоритмы на плюсики или настроил бы трамплин в матпакет.

Comment: Меня приводят в недоумение области с раздвоенной кривой, как в начале второго графика. Вы уверены, что это целевая функция является однозначной `y=f(x)`? Как бы вы провели кривую на этом наборе точек?

Comment: @Chorkov да, уверен. Я в вопросе говорил, что на самом деле координаты точек на графике - координаты двух рядом идущих проводов. По сути своей это две функции y=f(x), которые изменяются по похожим законам. Следующим шагом после фильтрации как раз и станет разделение этих двух кривых с дополнением координат в местах их отсутствия.

Comment: @nick_n_a мне необходимо выделить координаты точек кривых на фоне шума, а не сгладить

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/166693/

Comment: @goldstar_labs про фильтр Калмана знаю, пытался его реализовать, но так и не смог разобраться

Comment: Считаете среднеквадратическое (среднеарифметическое меньше ресурсов но хуже результат) отклонение каждой точки относительно 16 или 100 соседних, если оно выше определенного % (% подобрать) - то вместо абсолютного значения - ставим среднее. За тем сверху ещё раз сгладить, можно среднеарифметическим.

Comment: можете попробовать метод скользящего среднего, тут https://habr.com/ru/post/134375/ есть вроде даже с кодом, ответить предметно не могу, т.к. нет вашего кода (как у вас хранятся точки и т.п.)

Comment: "Но каким образом можно математически описать эту "плавность"?" скорость изменения функции описывается ее производной, если она больше определенного порогового значения, точку надо выкидывать, это шум. Но как быть с парой сигналов, я придумать навскидку не могу.